# How to inject view when selected item property changes in another view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to determine the best method to populate a region when the selected item of a data grid view changes.

I am using Prism.DryIoc in my WPF desktop application. It has several regions, each with corresponding loosely coupled views and viewmodels. When the selected item of this data grid changes, I want a different view to populate a different region.
These views do not have references to each other even though they are contained in the same module project file.

So far, I have tried using the IEventAggregator to publish that the selected item has changed.

```
public class MyObjectViewModel : BindableBase
{
   private IEventAggregator _ea;
   public MyObjectViewModel(IEventAggregator ea )
   {
      _ea = ea;
      //Do stuff here …
      Grid_SelectionChanged = new DelegateCommand(SelectObject, CanSelectObject);
   }
   private MyData _selectedObject;
   public MyData SelectedObject
   {
     get { return _selectedObject; }
     set
     {
       SetProperty(ref _selectedObject, value);
       _ea.GetEvent<MyObjectSelectionChangedEvent>().Publish(SelectedObject);                
      }
    } …
```

In my MyAppModule.cs file I have the following constructor where I subscribe to the event:

```
public MyAppModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator ea)
{
   _regionManager = regionManager;
   ea.GetEvent<MyObjectSelectionChangedEvent>().Subscribe(MyObjectSelectionChanged);
}
```

I have a corresponding method that reads a property from SelectedObject.ObjectName.

```
private void MyObjectSelectionChanged(MyObject myObject)
{
   Type myObjectType = null;
   switch (myObject.ObjectName)
   {
     case "objectA":
           myObjectType = typeof(Views.MyObjectA);
           break;
     case "objectB":
           myObjectType = typeof(Views.MyObjectB);
           break;
     ...
     default:
           myObjectType = typeof(Views.NoObjects);
           break;
   }
                        
    _regionManager.AddToRegion("TestDataRegion", deviceType);
}
```

When I debug this, the publish event is called but the above method is not. The subscribe method is called when the object is created.

- Am I pursuing the correct solution in order to dynamically load a view based on a selected item in the datagrid object?
- What am I missing to get my method called after publishing that the event changed?
- Is there a better way to handle this in Prism so that I don't have to have a dirty setter?

*EDIT: I have switched to use RegisterForNavigation and RequestNavigation. Thank you for the tip*

Comment: In my opinion you should use the navigation service of prism. The event aggregation is usefull for other things.

Comment: Dynamically populating regions is called `navigation` in prism...